# Scanner text file

Tags: java, file, text, nosuchelementexception

I'm writing code for a program which takes in words from a text file and arranges them into alphabetical order, but I can't seem to get the scanner working?

```
public static void Option1Method() throws IOException {
    FileWriter aFileWriter = new FileWriter("wordlist.txt", true);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(aFileWriter);
    String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a word");

    out.println(word);
    out.close();

    aFileWriter.close();

    String inputFile = "wordlist.txt";
    String outputFile = "wordlist.txt";
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(inputFile);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(fileReader);
    scan.nextLine;
    String inputLine;
    List<String> lineList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while ((inputLine = scan.nextLine()) != null) {
        lineList.add(inputLine);
    }
    fileReader.close();

    Collections.sort(lineList);

    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(outputFile);
    PrintWriter out1 = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
    for (String outputLine : lineList) {
        out1.println(outputLine);
    }
    out1.flush();
    out1.close();
    fileWriter.close();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Scanner#nextLine` is a method. You need to add parenthesis. Replace

```
scan.nextLine;
```

with

```
scan.nextLine();
             ^
```

Also `Scanner` uses `hasNextLine` to check for subsequent lines. Calling `scan.nextLine()` on an open file will eventually cause a `NoSuchElementException`. Replace:

```
while ((inputLine = scan.nextLine()) != null) {
  ...
}
```

with

```
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
   inputLine = scan.nextLine();
   lineList.add(inputLine);
}
```

Note that the first call to `scan.nextLine()` causes the first line to be consumed without being written to the sorted output file. Remove or comment this line if you intend all words to be written to file.